# bibliography inside longtable

Tags: biblatex, page-breaking, longtable

I am forced to use an official template for a CV, which wraps everything inside tabular environments (the rationale, I assume, being to reproduce exactly the dimensions and looks of an alternative Word template).

Anyway, the part that I'm struggling with is to include a bibliography spanning multiple pages. Is there a way to tell biblatex to insert page breaks after N items, or maybe a smarter version of longtable that does it automatically?

Here's an example where the content overflows,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\tabuDisableCommands{\def\autocite{}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\begin{longtabu}{|X|}
\hline
\printbibliography
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Edit: to clarify, I have to put everything within a frame of specific width and appearance. All the sections are typically wrapped in something like,

```
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}p{9.8 cm}}{{\bf 1e.   Total years research experience:}}   & \multicolumn{1}{|p{6.1 cm}|}{\hfill{}  \normalfont{
    xx years (PhD excluded)}}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}
```

It doesn't matter what exact environment I use (I only send the pdf output), but the frame and margins must be consistent.

Comment: you are using longtabu rather than longtable but either way it can not break within a single cell, you need to make each item be a separate row, but a longtable with one column does nothing, just put `\end{longtable}` before the bibliography and `\begin{longtable}` after it

Comment: I still need the frame and size consistent with the rest of the document that uses tabular environments for every section (see edit). It is true that a one-column table is a bit useless, so I guess I only need to fake the appearance of a tabular environment for this particular section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho there is not really possible to squeeze \printbibliography inside a longtable: There are lots of groupings involved and they clash with the grouping of tabular cells. If you want a frame around the bibliography, use tcolorbox. It can be easily adapted to all sorts of looks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\tabuDisableCommands{\def\autocite{}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0,sharp corners,breakable]
  \printbibliography
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the idea but the output I get from running this is not good: first, a blank page, then `enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0,sharp corners,breakable` verbatim, and most importantly, the content doesn't change page (overflows)

Comment: @baptiste, a small typo, change it to `[enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0,sharp corners,breakable]` (square brackets instead of curly ones).

Comment: Sorry about the typo ;-). gusbrs is right: it should be brackets.